# How to check if a table exists using python?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to check whether the table exists or not before inserting the data.
This is what i have tried:

```
def checkTables(tablename):
    stmt = "SHOW TABLES LIKE %s"%tablename          
    cursor.execute(stmt)
    result = cursor.fetchone()          
    return result
```

But it gives me error saying:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ctg_payload3' at line 1`

Comment: Is your syntax right for the parameter? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python depending on which db you are using, e.g. maybe `cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES LIKE ?", (tablename))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is not the best way.

As for my opinion, I will `show tables;`, then search the result.

And, I you cannot execute `show tables like tablename;`, no syntax like that.

edit 1

If you must do it in sql, use

```
 show table status like 'table_name';
```

`'` is needed for this sql.

Comment: You're welcome. And don't forget mark the answer when you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query string :`SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_mydb LIKE '%tablename%'` or

this one

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'my_database_name'
AND table_name LIKE '%tablename%'
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def checkTables(tablename):
    stmt = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '%s' "% ('%'+str(tablename)+'%')
    cursor.execute(stmt)
    result = cursor.fetchone()          
    return result
```